# Reading and Writing a SecretKey to a file

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm looking to be able to save a DES SecretKey to a file, so you can import and use it later on.
I've looked at a few routes, but they all seem a bit long winded, is there no conscise simple way of doing this?

Comment: Please explain what you've tried.

Comment: Haven't tried, rather read, Generating a key and then converting to bytes. But I can't find any clear instructions on how I would go about doing even this, the examples are always doing way more than I need.

Comment: Does [`Key.getEncoded()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getEncoded%28%29) not do what you want?

Comment: I don't really understand How i'm meant to use that method, and i can't find any decent examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear on a couple of things: how you're generating the key, and what format you have the key in.  If you don't have the key you can use keytool (a utility which comes with jdk) to generate it and put it into a file called a keystore.  You can also use the KeyGenerator class and the KeyStore class to programmatically do the same thing (both are documented pretty well and the [KeyStore javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) has an example which does exactly what you seem to want.)

A much less secure but easy way you can generate the key and put it into a text file as clear text.  Then you can just access it using a BufferedReader.  This is less secure because anyone with access to this file will know your key, but it's a little easier.

Comment: You see, whats the process of putting the key in a file as clear text? I can generate the key with KeyGenerator. But then I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the key into a plain text format to save in a text file.
The project is meerly to prove an idea so I'm not to worried about the security and integrity of the key.
Will be trying the example below though, KeyStore looks like it could fix my issue.

Comment: KeyGenerator.generateKey() returns an object of type SecretKey.  SecretKey.getEncoded() returns the key as a char[].  You can convert this to a string and save to in a text file.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the KeyStore java doc; I was having issues with this as well (my first attempt at any form of encryption) and this set me in the right direction.

Answer (score 10):

`javax.crypto.SecretKey extends java.security.Key`

`java.security.Key extends java.io.Serializable`

So if you trust the file-system to which you're storing keys, you can write out a key using `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` and read it in using `java.io.ObjectInputStream`.

```
ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
try {
  oout.writeObject(myKey);
} finally {
  oout.close();
}
```

and the input looks similar

```
Key key;
ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
try {
  key = (Key) oin.readObject();
} finally {
  oin.close();
}
```

To generate a key, you need a `KeyFactory` or [`SecretKeyFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html)

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
```

and then to generate a secret

```
factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
```

given a key spec that is appropriate to the algorithm.  See the [`KeySpec` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/KeySpec.html) for pointers to algorithm specific `KeySpec` implementations.

For DES, see [`DESKeySpec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/DESKeySpec.html) though you might want something [more modern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography_standards#Encryption_standards).

Comment: Not sure it's a good idea to dump a key into a file just like that, without any password protection.

Comment: @Bruno, you have to trust something.  If you're going to have a headless process that uses keys, then you either have to give whatever bootstraps it access to keys, or give it access to a key to a key store.  Keystore are great things, but for headless processes they don't solve the key protection problem, just push it back one layer.

Comment: Although you are right that you're "just pushing it back one layer", I'm with @Bruno on this because in some cases doing this is useful.  You can embed the password to your keystore in

Comment: your application. This way A) in case of accidental unauthorized access or copying there is less likelihood that the keys will be compromised because there are two pieces of information required to get at the keys.  B) if the server is compromised, although it wouldn't be impossible to get at the keys, as you pointed out, it will no longer be trivial, especially if the keystore is in a different system than the application.

Comment: However, it's a valid point that at some junction you must supply the password to get to the keys.

Comment: @Sanjeev, if you embed keystore passwords in the application, then anything with read access to the application binary, or memory access to the running application has access to the password and thereby the key.  When the keys are in a key file, you still have the file system problem, but the memory problem is limited to processes that can access the file-cache.  The latter category is smaller.  There are many excellent reasons to use key stores, but default suspicion of the file-system is not a sufficient reason unless you have a way to avoid storing passwords in the file-system.

Comment: The way I've done it in the past is that the password is supplied to an ant script at command line.  As far as access to the application binaries, I guess the point I'm trying to make is that it's less trivial to gain access to the file system which has the keystore and have access to the file system with the binaries (in memory or on disk) and also have to extract the password from the binaries than to just gain access to a single text file with keys in plain text.  It all depends on your applications requirements and your systems configuration.

Comment: Also, as far as "excellent reasons to use key stores", indeed there are many excellent reasons and one of them is to password protects your private keys.  That's one of oracle/sun's explicit reasons for providing key store functionality.

Comment: I think that this is most direct answer for the original question. I wanted this for a trivial CS assignment, where password storage isn't important.

Comment: I agree, the OP pretty specifically asked for exactly this simple answer, and not the usual "recommended" one that most other answers gave, which as we all know is to use key stores.

Answer (score 7):

The most "natural" way to save a `SecretKey` into a file in Java is to use [a `KeyStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html): that's exactly what it's for (although you can save certificates too, of course).

The [example in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) shows how to save a private key and a secret key. It will also encrypt it with a protection parameter (password here).